# Track checkbox checked with email or other info

Tags: html, tags, google-tag-manager

I'm working with a client who has an order form, and needs to track that each customer selected "I agree to terms and conditions" checkbox at checkout. They'll need to be able to go back and check this data.

The checkout is via a ClickFunnels order form. I added the checkbox via HTML, no problem there. The customers needs to be able to track that each client clicks the agree button, and it needs to be associated with the email or phone number.

Was thinking I may be able to do this with the User ID of the Google Tag Manager? I could assign the input from user email to the User ID in Tag Manager?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Provide a code example

Comment: I don't have any code written except for the checkbox. `<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  <div class="tac">
  <input type="checkbox" name="tac"> I agree to the <a href="http://tac-link-here/"> terms and conditions<br>
  </div>
</form>`

Comment: What I need to do is create a report (in Analytics) for each form submission that shows the customer email, and wether they click the "agree to terms and conditions" checkbox.